# Node.js server CPU goes up to 100%, Memory around 30-50%

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm running a node.js server as a chat system for my website. However, I noticed 2 things:

1. The memory of the server keeps climbing up.  I thought it was a memory leak at first but then I read about this post:
   [node.js - possible http server memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917533/node-js-possible-http-server-memory-leak)
   However, my memory keeps climbing up until like 30-50. Is it normal? (I'm not sure it's going to keep increasing since my server crushed every 4-5 hours, 100% CPU, see 2 for details).
2. The CPU increases to 99%+ after several hours of running. (I'm running the server with forever, I don't know it's relevant or not.) When the CPU is 99+%, the memory is about 30% - 50%.

My question is:
Usually, what kind of issue will cause this? Could it be a lot of not removed listeners? Callbacks or anything? I checked my forever error log but there is nothing.

---

Here are some codes that I found maybe troublesome(they are located in different files), not sure if they are helpful. Thanks so much for your help!

```
        this.events.addListener('update', o_.bind(function(package) {
            if(this.clear != 0){
                delete this.sessions[this.clear];
                this.events.removeListener('update',arguments.callee,false);
            }
            var _package = package.toJSON();
            if(package.type == 'status' && package.status == 'offline') {
                var sids = Object.keys(this.sessions), sid, sess;
                for(sid in this.sessions) {
                    sess = this.sessions[sid];
                    if(sess.data('username') == package.username) {
                        if(sess.listeners.length)
                            sess.send(200, {type: 'goodbye'});
                        delete this.sessions[sid];
                        this.events.removeListener('update',arguments.callee,false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, this));
    };


setInterval(o_.bind(this._expireConns, this), 500);
User.prototype._expireConns = function() {
    var conn,
        noop = JSON.stringify({type: 'noop'}),
        noop_headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': noop.length
        };
    for(var i = 0; i < this.listeners.length; i++) {
        conn = this.listeners[i].connection;
        if( conn!=null && ((Date.now() - conn._idleStart) >= conn._idleTimeout - 2000) ) {
            this.listeners[i].writeHead(200, noop_headers);
            this.listeners[i].end(noop);
            this.listeners.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
};

    this.reapInterval = options.reapInterval || 60 * 1000;
    this.clear = options.clear || 0;

    if(this.reapInterval !== -1) {
        setInterval(function(self) {
            self.reap(self.maxAge);
        }, this.reapInterval, this);
    }

Hub.prototype.reap = function(ms) {
    var threshold = +new Date - ms,
        sids = Object.keys(this.sessions);
    for(var i = 0, len = sids.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var sid = sids[i], sess = this.sessions[sid];
        if(sess.lastAccess < threshold) {
         this.events.emit('update', new packages.Offline(sess.data('username')));
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: id look around for infinite loops, maybe?

Comment: in the loop in your example `for(var i = 0; i < this.listeners.length; i++) {` i notice that inside of that loop there is a way for `i` to be decremented, and this could potentially cause an infinite loop. Put a console.log in the middle of that loop and see how many times it logs

Comment: @Markasoftware Hi I just checked out the issue. Looks like it's fine? But I'm not sure tho because my server won't crush until like at least 3-4 hours

Comment: the only way to REALLY test this is to comment out certain sections, see if the issue occurs, if it does continue to comment a different section instead, until you've found the section causing the error. Then post that code here, and we can help. Until then, this question is really just too general for us to be able to diagnose

Comment: @Markasoftware Thanks so much for your help buddy but this whole thing has like 6 files with lots of lines in total. So I'm just trying to have a big idea here first. So it sounds like a loop issue? a listener issue? callback issue? Thanks anyway :)